# Is there any way to know if redis database is on use?

Tags: redis, node-redis

Is there any way to know using node-redis if a redis DB is being used by another process? Something like this:

1. Process A connect to db0.
2. Process B check if db0 is used
3. Process B connect to db1 because db0 is used.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: https://redis.io/commands/client-list

Comment: Hi Guy! Thx for the answer. You are totally right. :D

Answer (score 0):

[CLIENT LIST](https://redis.io/commands/client-list) command should give you this info.